# What are the common mistakes when you are a good coder in C and PHP and you start coding in Java ? What are good tips when switching?

Tags: java, php, c

What apsects of Java are the most diificult to learn when coming from such a background?  What common mistakes do people make ? What are the top timesaving and produtivtity increasing tricks ?

If you had a room of C/PHP coders who were about to start development using Java what advise would you give ?

This is my list of topics so far (in no particular order):

- Use jodatime instead of the standard
  library , and also less importantly
  the guava library.
- Arrays are zero indexed
- I'd also highlight the
  pass-by-value/reference aspects of
  Java, and the fact that

  > ```
  > String s1 = new String("test"); 
  > String s2 = new String("test"); 
  > if(s1 == s2) // will be false 
  > if(s1.equals(s2)) // will be true
  > ```
- Introduce the concept of design
  patterns and give a quick overview.
- Introduce Spring (it will be used) and the concept of
  dependency injection

Is there anything obvious I am missing.

Comment: Array's are zero indexed in C as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The automatic garbage collecting doesn't mean that you should give up memory usage optimization.**

Answer (score 7):

Few points that PHP developer needs to know to code in Java:

- Different type of collections are available in Java, in PHP only arrays is most commonly used so many PHP developers won't be aware of collections concepts.
- Packaging : packaging is not generally used in PHP so they need to understand concepts like jar, war etc
- Threads & Thread safety : if PHP is the only language they know threads is going to be entirely new concept.
- Different application servers in Java, in PHP world it's just Apache.
- Design patterns: Java world much emphasis is given for design patterns than in php.

Comment: There are ways to run PHP in a multi-threaded way. Not everything in PHP is inherently thread-safe though. There's also not just Apache.

Answer (score 5):

Not using proper Object-Oriented design but procedural. A classical example is switch or many if/else versus polymorphism:

```
//procedural way of computing the salary of an employee    
if(employeeType == JUNIOR) {
    salary = //junior salary calculation logc;   
} else if(employeeType == MID_LEVEL)
    salary = //mid_level salary calculation logc;   
} else if(employeeType == SENIOR) {
    salary = //senior salary calculation logc;   
}


//OOP way
Employee employee = EmployeeFactory.getEmployee(JUNIOR);
salary = employee.calculateSalary();
//where employee is an interface having calculateSalary method; 
//also there are classes for JuniorEmployee, MidLevelEmployee and SeniorEmployee
```

Comment: +1 for touching on this very important issue. I'd give you more +s if I could :)

Answer (score 2):

The biggest thing about Java compared with the languages you are talking about is the whole deal with Object Orientation. You can get by as a C or PHP programmer working almost entirely in a procedural way and if you want to be any good at Java you need to understand Object Orientation and understand it well.

If you can make sure they have learned that, not only will it make them better Java programmers, but it will be useful to them with any other languages they learn in future.

Comment: Is there a good simple example anywhere, a program written procedurally and then compared to OO. I guess I could write one myself, but is there a nice clear already available example around ?

Comment: I don't know of one in particular but I do remember back when I was learning to use Java I learned a lot from the "Essence Of OOP Using Java" tutorials here: http://dickbaldwin.com/tocint.htm

Comment: Actually a problem for many PHP programmers is that they overcompensate with **in-your-face-OOP** coding styles (instead of nice APIs and object graphs) to make up for the perceived lack of object-orientation capabilities in PHP.

Comment: @mario: that sounds interesting, care to elaborate?

Comment: @Javier: Recent language changes brought some Javaisms onto PHP, which are not often senseful in a hybrid language. With a grain of salt: [PHP Cargo Cult Programming](http://milki.erphesfurt.de/EPCCP.pdf). Also some PHP frameworks take the design patterns idea too far and can lead to suboptimal/obscure application structures.

Answer (score 1):

*For two of your remarks :*

> I'd also highlight the pass-by-value/reference aspects of Java, and
>   the fact that ...

One of the best books to deeply understand coding problems is  :"Extreme Java" by Joshua Bloch so:

```
String s1 = new String("test"); // bad coding

String s1 = "test"; // sufficient
```

Many and many other samples inside.

If you are obliged to code tomorrow, read inside concerned paragraph before coding, and take a pause to understand that Java is another mind world, even if it `C` children.

First time it seems very difficult, but soon it is more clear, and powerful.

> Introduce the concept of design patterns and give a quick overview.

THE book designed for beginners to understand Java and OOP problems : *Head First Design Patterns*.

> Tips/sample

Have a look at `Collections` or `Pattern` in Java package classes to understand good writing,

Comment: could you please expand on why you recommend suggested resources as an answer to the question asked?